# How can I ignore type errors when hot-reloading in a react app using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on typescript + react but it throws "compile" error. Here is my config. I would like to check types but still want to build and hot-reload. Could someone tell me how I force to compile?

**Sorry, I know how to fix this error itself but I would like to compile whenever I get any kind of typescript errors.And I don't want to put @ts-ignore everywhere**

[image]

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Set `"noImplicitAny": false` or use `ReactNode` as the children type.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you know how to compile no matter I get typescript errors?

Comment: The point of typescript is not to ignore all type errors during development.

Comment: I would like to show errors on the terminal and validate types and throw type errors during the CI phase.

Comment: If you are not ready, you can just remove the TS.

Answer (score 1):

The `noImplicitAny` property should be set to `false` not `true`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Sorry, I know how to fix this particular issue but don't know how to compile always. Do you have any ideas? I don't want typescript block compile even it throws an error

Comment: You can add `// @ts-nocheck` at the top of your Typescript files

Comment: Hmm, I want to still check the types. For example, eslint will still compile even it has lint error. I would like to do the same

Answer (score 0):

I dont think building with type errors is ideal, but...

I think that the best approach would be to create a separe tsconfig to be used when running in `watch` mode, where all the noImplicit* are set to false.